# QGIS "Delete ring" no longer works

Tags: qgis, editing, features

I have QGIS 2.4.0. Until just today, the "Delete ring" feature worked just fine. Now it no longer works at all. I rebooted and even reinstalled QGIS 2.4, and it didn't fix the problem.

But I also still have QGIS 2.2.0. "Delete ring" works fine on that.

Why did "Delete ring" on QGIS 2.4 stop working?

Comment: Now it also stopped working in QGIS 2.2. When I try using "Delete Ring" in 2.2, it comes up with an error message that says "Snap tolerance: Could not snap segment."

Comment: Now I notice that it works if I start a new project that includes just the layer in question. It doesn't work on the larger project that uses multiple layers.

Comment: Tim, you are right. Delete ring worked much better in earlier versions. I use 2.8.1 Vienna, and are able to delete rings only if a zoom in and clicking the empty space within the ring. I played around with snapping options and tolerance, without any effect. Hope it'll be fixed soon.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't used any features which require **Snapping** so this is not a difinitive answer but I hope it might lead you to some kind of solution:

*Settings* > *Options...* > *Digitizing*

Check that the *Default snap mode* is **not off**. You may need to add a value for the tolerance.

[image: Digitizing options]

Afterwards, you can access the options for snapping via *Settings* > *Snapping Options...*

[image: Snapping options]

This will give you a set of options from a new dock window which opens at the bottom of the main window shown in the following image (this is assuming the **snapping options opened in a dock window** box is checked from the *Digitizing* options shown in the first image)

[image: Snapping options window]

Play around again with the values/options and hope that something works!

Comment: I just tried this, but it's still messed up.

Comment: Ring tool still seems to be broken in in QGIS 3.2.1

Comment: @maskin - You should [submit a bug report](https://issues.qgis.org/projects/qgis) :)

Comment: @Joseph True, I need to make some time to do that, and setup the accounts. :-)

Comment: @Joseph Bug raised, https://issues.qgis.org/issues/19784

Comment: @maskin - Great! Thanks very much for reporting this issue :)

Comment: @Joseph my bug is about thin rings (0/small areas) the tool does seem to work on rings with a significant area, at least in QGIS 3.2.2-1.  My tests were using the add ring and delete ring buttons, so I think we might need some example files if it still isn't working...

Comment: @maskin - Thanks for keeping this updated. Hopefully they'll provide a fix for it soon!

Comment: @Joseph I don't think the tool is broken, at least for rings with a significant area.  There is a a workaround using the node tool.  But I am getting off topic

Answer (score 2):

Snap tolerance is saved in the project file. So it may help to create a new project file, adding all layers one by one.

Or investigate the .qgs file with a good text editor (like notepad++).

Answer (score 2):

In my QGIS 2.4.0, the "delete ring" doesn't work when I have "on the fly" CRS transformation turned on.

Answer (score 1):

You might test the idea that you have non-compliant data in your layer. Create a new layer by making a very small buffer (0.0001 m for instance) and then carry out the operation on that. There are also tools in the vector menu to test for errors in the data.